# SQL select the last 3 dates from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with lots of fields in mysql

I need a query to return (**in the same raw!**) the top last 3 dates  (dates can have large gaps between them)

ie:

```
2012/01/20
2012/01/18
2012/01/12
2012/01/10
2012/01/04
```

etc...

Any help will be appreciated

I must get them in the same row!

This is the query I am trying to use with no success:

```
SELECT a.id, a.thedate, b.id AS id1, b.thedate AS thedate1, c.id AS id2, c.thedate as thedate2
FROM mytable AS a INNER JOIN mytable AS b ON a.id = b.id INNER JOIN mytable AS c ON b.id=c.id
WHERE c.thedate = SELECT MAX(thedate)
```

Comment: What's the datatype of the date column in your table?

Comment: this is a basic question. give us the query you have written so far.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT :

```
SELECT group_concat(date) FROM (SELECT date FROM my_table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3) AS temp
```

Comment: He want them returned in the same row (??!?!?)

Comment: So, try SELECT date FROM my_table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3;

Comment: This give you again three rows.

Comment: Sorry, SELECT group_concat(date) FROM (SELECT date FROM my_table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 3) AS temp;

Answer (score 2):

**Corrected-**

```
 SELECT group_concat(date) FROM ( select date from table_name order by date desc limit 3) as a
```

Comment: It will concat all dates, because LIMIT will not work like you expect

Comment: @matino thanx for correcting me, let me think something else for this

Comment: You beat me with seconds :) It's ok now!

Comment: Thank you very much, but I must be able to address the results as thedate, thedate1, thedate2 that's why I tried to use something like the query in my original questions

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.date ) 
FROM (
SELECT date
FROM my_table
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 3
) AS a
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I must be able to address the results as thedate, thedate1, thedate2 that's why I tried to use something like the query in my original question